# Making a Terminal Server in Python

Tags: python

The company I work for has been using a terminal software that we connect to using Anzio Lite (using Telnet) for many years. This software is called OMNI by ACCEO Solutions and is not going anywhere and is the default in all of the franchises. This was created 35 years ago and my users are quite used to working with this sort of software and I was thinking of making something similar for some tools.

I'd like to know if there is a way to make software like it in python?

[image]

Comment: The `curses` library maybe?

Comment: `urwid` https://urwid.org/examples/index.html

Comment: There are *many* python modules that can help build text user interfaces. Take a look around, see what you can find, look at the examples and see if it's easy to work with. If you run into problems once you start writing code, we'd be happy to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are modern Python libraries for creating full-fledged "TUI" (text user interface) applications.

The most complete of which is "textual" https://textual.textualize.io/ - and there is my own "terminedia" which allows application development - but is far less ready for structured applications or documented at the moment - https://pypi.org/project/terminedia/

Note that the "terminal emulator" itself is the program where "telnet" (or equivalent) is executed - and it has to support control sequences for changing text color, positioning the cursor, etc... usually known as "ANSI control sequences". The program with a TUI can then be executed in any server, and the interface should just work.